# change CSS on the fly via firebug?

Tags: css

Is it possible when using firebug to debug css issues, to chagne a value of a css rule and then see how it changes the page dynamically /on the fly?

Comment: Do you mean to modify AND alter the actual CSS file on your computer? If so, no. If you mean to just change the values of what you *see* then yeah, that's one of the most popular features.

Comment: No, I mean open a session of a site, launch firebug and then change the style for an element and have it change my session.  Not the code on the server.  I've tried changing it but it doesn't seem to work.  Just want to see if its possible, and that it's not just me doing it the wrong way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, simply click the variable you want to change in the firebug panel. The variable should appear as a text box which you can edit immediately but not permanently, to show you how a style will effect an element.

Comment: Mick, that's exactly what I'm trying to do.  Dynamically check what a style change will look like.  But which tab should I do this in?  I'm in firebuglite, under HTML.  I select an element from the html code that appears, and then on the right hand side of the pop up window, i select the Style tab (as opposed to Computed or DOM).  Is this where I should be?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly where to edit the variables. If you have an inline style you can also temporarily edit the variables under the HTML tab in the left-hand panel.

Comment: I got it.  I right click on the items to change. I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can** dynamically edit and view the changes on the fly.**But Firebug does not save changes to your theme**, you will need to copy the changes you’ve made in Firebug and paste them into your theme’s style.css in the appropriate spot. These links will be of help :

http://www.tutorial9.net/tutorials/web-tutorials/quick-easy-css-development-with-firebug/

http://www.studiopress.com/tips/using-firebug.htm